# FDClientDataSet does not present latest data on database table

Tags: database, oracle, delphi

I developed a client/server database.

The server hosts the oracle database, the one I manipulate with the client (in android).
Everything works correctly, but when I insert/delete/modify a record, the database shows all the changes correctly, but the information I have on the FDClientDataSet is the one that does not contain my latest changes. I was doing some workaround like `ClientDataset.Active:= False` and later setting it to True, that was working but causes an exception when running the app on the android device.

I have tried tons of things, like update, `ApplyUpdates` methods, etc, but nothing works.  Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Not that it helps you much but with traditional ClientDataSets, doing an ApplyUpdates followed by a CDS.Refresh would be sufficient to sync the local data with the server database.  Have you tried to monitor the SQL that should be sent back to the server when ApplyUpdates is called?

Comment: After the ApplyUpdates, perform the CDS method 'CommitUpdates', this signals to the clientdataset that all changed data can be seen as committed data, and will be reflected as such

Comment: I can not find the CommitUpdates method on ClientDataSet :S Sorry about my lack of experience with this component. I would really appreciate if you give me more details about performing CommitUpdates method and how to apply it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and comments. I fixed it using AppyUpdates(-1), then Refresh methods. Finally I assigned the data from the dataprovider to the clientdataset. I used this link to realize that it could fix my problem. Hope it helps to somebody else: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Assigning_Data_Directly